# Android execute chmod command for data/data/com.android.providers.telephony

Tags: android, permissions, adb, chmod, pull

hi gus could anybody tell me how i can execute the adb pull command to pull the mmssms.db file. Otherwise i need to chmod the permission of the file to 775. I tried do both but got only permission denied..

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access this file on production hardware, unless you root your phone. Unless you are writing your own firmware, you should not be working with this file.